# CPU Usage of individual processes via TOP/Dumpsys cpuinfo

Tags: cpu, android, cpu-usage, top, resource-usage

**Context:** When I run an Android App alone, I get a CPU Usage of 20% (using dumpsys cpuinfo). However, when I run another app in parallel with it, then the CPU Usages goes down, lets say to 13-12%. I observed the same behavior with TOP Command. These values goes further down, if I run other apps in parallel with them. Indeed, the CPU load increases.

My understanding was that these two commands (TOP, Dumpsys cpuinfo) returns the absolute CPU Usage (Single CPU). But it doesn't seem to be true. Somehow these value have a relationship with the load, that's why they go down when the overall load increases.

I can't find any details on how these two are related. Is the CPU reported values somehow dependent on the overload ? If yes, how ? Any explanations?

Comment: Maybe it depends on power scaling? Like the CPU is running in low power mode, at a slow frequency. Then when you add more apps, it speeds up to a higher frequency?

Comment: @WaleedHamra can you elaborate it a bit further on how?